# How can i add validation to this login form with out it redirecting to the wp-login.php page

Tags: login, forms, validation

Im using the code as posted on the website below, to create a hard coded login form.
http://www.wprecipes.com/add-a-login-form-on-your-wordpress-theme

What would be the best way of incorperating some validation with this or using the default wordpress error messages?

the whole point in hard coding the form is that the user isnt  taken away from the content to the default wp-login.php page throughout the login process.

Regards, Tom Kiddle

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `wp_login_form()`? ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form))

Comment: I could but this will still redirect the user to the default wp-login.php if the password is incorrect, this is exactly what im trying to avoid. Unless you know a way to use that 'wp_login_form()' that i dont?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I post an answer. Solution here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-you-stop-wp_login_form-redirecting-to-wp-login-on-fail?replies=13